# insert... select with only some fields

Tags: mysql, select, insert

I have two tables in my database and I want to find all records that exist in the first table but not the second. Then I want to copy the id and name (but not the rest of the fields) from the first table into the second, and set a value for a third column in the second table. I'm using this to get the records:

```
SELECT table1.* FROM table1 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE
table2.id = table1.id)
```

but I'm not sure of the proper syntax for the INSERT command. I think it would start

```
INSERT INTO table2 [id,name]
```

but what do I specify after that?

Answer (score 4):

Like this:

```
INSERT INTO table2 (col1, col2, col3) VALUES (1, 2, 3);
```

If you're doing the insert from the select, it will look like this:

```
INSERT INTO table2 (id, name, thirdCol)
SELECT (table1.id, table1.name, 'Whatever value') FROM table1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT id FROM table2 WHERE table2.id = table1.id);
```

Comment: I'm getting an error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in [file.php] on line 6. Is there something I need to do other than specify the value for column 3 as a string?